# How to examine JVM execution stack to determine cause of stack corruption

Tags: java, windows, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a JUnit test which looks more or less like this:

```
double doubleValue = 100.0 + 1E-14;
long longValue = nativeInvokeWrapper(doubleValue, ...);
assertEquals(doubleValue, Double.longBitsToDouble(longValue));
```

## Background

The function `nativeInvokeWrapper` calls another Java function which in turn invokes a JNI function which ultimately calls a `__stdcall` "C" function, passing `doubleValue` as an  argument. The "C" function returns a 64-bit value that is bitwise equal to the double argument it received, and this return value gets propagated out until it is returned by `nativeInvokeWrapper`.

The point is that the expected return value of `nativeInvokeWrapper` is a `long` that is bitwise equal to `doubleValue`.

## The Issue

- When I run the JUnit test by itself, it passes.
- When I run the whole JUnit test suite, all the other tests pass but this one fails.
- When I run the whole JUnit test suite with a breakpoint set in the above test and step through it, it works just fine.

It is possible that my native function might be corrupting the JVM state in some subtle way... What's interesting is that if I read the value of the variable `longValue` twice, the problem seems to go away. For example, if I change the test code to:

```
double doubleValue = 100.0 + 1E-14;
long longValue = nativeInvokeWrapper(doubleValue, ...);
long longValue2 = longValue;
double doubleValue2 = Double.longBitsToDouble(longValue2);
if (doubleValue != doubleValue2)
{
    String msg = "d=" + doubleValue + ", d2=" + doubleValue2 + "\n" +
                 "l=" + longValue + ", l2=" + longValue2;
    throw new RuntimeException(msg);
}
```

And run the whole JUnit test suite, it throws:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: d=100.00000000000001, d2=NaN
l=4636737291354636289, l2=
  4636737291354636289
```

Note that the two `double` values are different, but the `long` values are the same.

When I step through in the debugger, everything works. It's as if by forcing a "read" of `longValue` before it is needed to be passed to the `Double.longBitsToDouble()` method, the state corruption issue goes away.

## Help!

What I'm looking for is ideas on how to debug this/determine the root cause. Stepping through in the regular Eclipse debugger isn't useful, as stated above, because it seems as though reading `longValue` cures the problem.

What other things can I look at? What other tools can I use to look at the internal state of the Java thread's execution stack to see if something has become corrupted?

UPDATE: If I turn off JIT (run the JVM with `-Xint`), everything works. So this has to do with some assumption or state specific to JIT-compiled code...

Comment: So basically the `assertEquals` fails because the values are different? And if you force a read it works? So what do you get when you print the value twice? If your assumption is correct, two different values should be printed.

Comment: Sadly, no, I tried that. However, if I introduce a temporary variable of type `double`, you can see there are 2 diff't double values (I'll update the question above).

Comment: Can you share the code for `nativeInvokeWrapper()` and the corresponding JNI part so we can try a run?

Comment: It's possible that you triggered some JIT bug. What's your JVM version and OS/architecture? Could you post the results when running with +PrintAssembly? You could also try with +PrintNMethods or +PrintStubCode to get a better insight into JVM/native area.